# iOS - How To Switch Off Frame Guidelines Of Views In Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I mistakenly pressed some key and these guidelines now showed up. How do I turn them off?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under Editor --> Canvas --> Show Bounds Rectangles

[image: Hide/Show Interface Builder Bounds Rectangles]